# Where can I set section index title size in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I added sectionIndexTitles. Where can I set section index title size? I need to change a width.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
 return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These indexTitles only define the "titled scrollBar" on the right... for your real section titles you're probably using `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`. If you want to have more control over those section titles, use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`instead. (and return an `UILabel` eg).